# For Each loop inside a For Each loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, foreach, runtime-error, vba

I have 2 sheets, so I want to `loop` the suppliers in the two ranges (they should always match, however the ccc-name will have some extra text added behind, hence the `replace`).

My issue is that I, obviously, cannot run cc and ccc simultaneously, but I need to compare cc and ccc. How can I make something like that possible?

```
    For Each cc In rngMyRange
        For Each ccc In Worksheets(10).Range("F3:F" & lastrow2).Cells

            Dim ContactID As String, ContactID2 As String
            ContactID = Sheets(10).Range("F" & ccc.Row).Value
            ContactID = Replace(ContactID, ContactID, cc)

            Debug.Print ContactID

            If cc Like ContactID Then
                If Sheets(1).Range("M" & cc.Row).Value Like "AN*" Then
                    Sheets(1).Range("M" & cc.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(10).Range("G" & ccc.Row)
                End If
            End If

        Next ccc
    Next cc
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the mid command?

Comment: No, I have not @Balinti. How should that help me? :-)

Comment: I guess I could loop through the range in worksheet(10) looking for a match with the cc. If there is a match, then do all the stuff and move to next cc, etc. Can you help?

Comment: Can you give examples as to what a ccc and a cc look like? I have no idea what you're working with at this point. Do you only want to compare them if they are on the same row? Becasue right now each of them will be compared with the each of the others. So you may get a match... between 1 and 3 for example.

Comment: Hi @DavidG sorry if it was very unclear. So basically, I am working with some suppliers. So cc and ccc is the same supplier just different ranges (if it makes sense). I have added my new code below, this is working (so far) - I am gonna test it some more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it slightly different :)

```
     For Each cc In rngMyRange
        For Each ccc In Worksheets(10).Range("F3:F" & lastrow2).Cells

            Dim FoundCell As Range
            Dim ContactID As String

                ContactID = Sheets(10).Range("F" & ccc.Row).Value

                If ContactID Like cc & "*" Then
                    ContactID = Replace(ContactID, ContactID, cc)
                End If

            Set FoundCell = Sheets(10).Columns(6).Find(what:=ContactID & "*", _
                                                             LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                             LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                If cc Like ContactID Then
                    If Sheets(1).Range("M" & cc.Row).Value Like "AN*" Then
                        Sheets(1).Range("M" & cc.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(10).Range("G" & ccc.Row)
                    Else
                        ' Do nothing
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                ' Not found
            End If
        Next ccc
    Next cc
```